# Expression of the inverse function of $f(x)=e^{-\varepsilon x}\sinh(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, hyperbolic-pde

I would like to know if there is a way of finding the inverse function of $f(x)=e^{-\varepsilon x}\sinh(x)$ with $-1<\varepsilon<0$.
It seems there is no simple way even if we consider Lambert or Gudermann-like functions.

Comment: if you substitute $z=e^{x}$, you seek to solve for $z$ the equation $z-1/z=2yz^\epsilon$. This has no closed form solution for arbitirary $\epsilon$.

Comment: If someone found a simple expression, what would you do with it?

Comment: It's a question from one of my (bright) student from a ballistics problem, the solution gives this expression.

Comment: By the Lagrange inversion formula, the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series expansion of the inverse is equal to the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the expansion of ($xe^{\varepsilon x}\mathrm{csch}\, x)^n$. (Note that $\mathrm{csch}\, x = x^{-1}-\frac 16x+\cdots$.) I doubt whether this fact will be of any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y=e^{- \epsilon x} \sinh (x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1-\epsilon )^n+(-1)^{n+1} (1+\epsilon )^n}{2 n!}\,x^n$$ Now use [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) using the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term as given by Morse and Feshbach.

This will give
$$x=y+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n y^n$$ the first coefficients being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & \epsilon  \\
 3 & \frac{1}{6} (3 \epsilon -1) (3 \epsilon +1) \\
 4 & \frac{2}{3} \epsilon  (2 \epsilon -1) (2 \epsilon +1) \\
 5 & \frac{1}{120} (5 \epsilon -3) (5 \epsilon -1) (5 \epsilon
   +1) (5 \epsilon +3) \\
 6 & \frac{2}{15} \epsilon  (3 \epsilon -2) (3 \epsilon -1) (3
   \epsilon +1) (3 \epsilon +2) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Hmmm... A polynomial approximation for something with a logarithmic asymptotic? It holds for small $y$, of course, but I'm afraid the gunners (or missile launchers) won't go too far with it...

Comment: @fedja. I did not write to use five or six terms. Plot $y$ and the expansion for, say, fifty terms. Does it look bad ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Have you tried it for not too small $y$ yourself? (I'll allow you 100 terms if you want, but go up to $y=15$). The problem is not the number of terms but a finite (and not very large) radius of convergence of the Taylor series at $0$. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that an inverse exists only for bijective functions. But you can decompose your function into bijective pieces and consider the partial inverses of your function.

Let's write one part of the defining equations of the inverse.

$$e^{−ϵx}\sinh(x)=y$$
$$e^{−ϵx}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}−e^{−x})=y$$

We see, this equation defines a $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic dependence
of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($e^{ϵx},e^x$). Therefore we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of only elementary functions/operations we can read from the equation.

If $\left(ϵ\in\mathbb{N}\right)$ or if $\left(ϵ\in\mathbb{Q}\right) \land \left(x\in\mathbb{R}\right)$, the equation is related to a polynomial equation of $e^x$, and $x$ is an algebraic expression of logarithms of algebraic expressions of y then.
This answers the question if the equation has solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$e^{-ϵx}\sinh(x)=y$$
$$e^{−ϵx}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}−e^{−x})=y$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(e^{2x}-1)e^{-ϵx-x}=y$$
$x\to \ln(z)$:
$$\frac{1}{2}(z^2-1)z^{-ϵ-1}=y$$
$$\frac{1}{2}z^{-ϵ+1}-\frac{1}{2}z^{-ϵ-1}-y=0$$
$$-2yz^{ϵ+1}+z^2-1=0$$

If $\left(ϵ\in\mathbb{N}\right)$ or if $\left(ϵ\in\mathbb{Q}\right) \land \left(z\in\mathbb{R}\right)$, this equation is related to an algebraic equation over $\mathbb{C}$ and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.
For $\left(ϵ\neq -1\}\right) \land \left(y\neq 0\right)$, the equation is also related to a trinomial equation then.

If $\left(ϵ\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}\right) \land \left(y\neq 0\right)$, the equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) ${}_1\Psi_1$ therefore.

So we get a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of ${}_1\Psi_1$ give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)

Answer (score 0):

As noted, for general $\epsilon \in (-1,0)$ the solution is not elementary. But for some $\epsilon$ it is.  For example, for $\epsilon = -1/2$, Maple solves it as

`x = -2*ln(2)-ln(3)+2*ln((((54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(2/3)-12)/(54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+ 48)^(1/2))^(1/3))^(1/2)+((12*y*3^(1/2)*(54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(1/3)-(((54 *y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(2/3)-12)/(54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(1/3))^(1/2)*( 54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(2/3)+12*(((54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(2/3)-12)/( 54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(1/3))^(1/2))/(54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(1/3)/(( (54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(2/3)-12)/(54*y^2+6*(81*y^4+48)^(1/2))^(1/3))^(1/2 ))^(1/2))`

If you have this type of solution, is it of any use to you at all?  I doubt it.